# Reference 3rd party .dll inside WMI class without GAC

Tags: .net, wmi

I'm developing a custom `WMI` class which returns a couple of string properties. This `WMI` class uses an external 3rd party `.dll` file (e.g. `something.dll`) located on a fixed location `C:\Test`. What I would like to do is reference/use classes from this `.dll` file inside of my `WMI` class and avoid using `GAC` (registering and installing `something.dll` using `gacutil` and `installutil`).

Is there a way to basically tell `WMI` "load `something.dll` directly from `C:\Test` location and not from `GAC`"?
Is there any article or online documentation that explains how `WMI` loads these external assembly files?

Comment: WMI uses COM under the hood, the basic way that it is usable from almost any language.  COM has gritty DLL Hell problems, caused by registration being machine-wide.   That makes intentionally avoiding the GAC a mistake.  But if you have to then you need to implement the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to help the CLR to find the assembly.  Very important that you can subscribe that event long before the assembly is needed, shouldn't be a major problem in a WMI provider.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, do check if the ILMerge utility can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and advice. In the end, I opted not to avoid GAC and went with _ILMerge_ utility.